# How use data from Color Array (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, swift4

I use a delegate to send data back to the VC.

I pass the data and the textfile, but I also need to send data from the array

How can i use data from array **(CardColor: (ColorArrayTwo)))** <-- in the code below

*CardColor is UIColor*

```
var ColorArrayTwo = [UIColor]()

self.delegate?.AddCard(CompanyName: "\(CNField.text!)", CardColor: (ColorArrayTwo??????))
```

**AddCard**

```
protocol AddDelegate {
    func AddCard(CompanyName: String, CardColor: UIColor)
}
```

Comment: pass index in ColorArrayTwo .like for data in ColorArrayTwo { }

Comment: @IOS How do I do it I do not really understand

Comment: where you want to use this code?

Comment: i send data through self.delegate?.AddCard(CompanyName: "\(CNField.text!)", CardColor: (ColorArrayTwo))

Comment: just add AddCard method code.you got CardColor and CompanyName in method?

Comment: you know how to implement delegate method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this code 
changes this code

```
protocol AddDelegate {
    func AddCard(CompanyName: String, CardColor: [UIColor])
}

for Data in ColorArrayTwo {
    lbltitle.textColor = Data
}

======OR====

lbltitle.textColor = ColorArrayTwo[1]
```

Comment: the second solution helped and i used ColorArrayTwo[0]